# How to Deploy Node js Rest API in SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created REST API for fetching the products details from SQL db. As of now I have only my dbconfig file where I have added the SQL database configuration. Now , I need to deploy this REST API to SharePoint.

My front end - Angular

Any steps to be done ?

In ASP.Net , we used to build the project, get the dll file & deploy that in IIS. But in node js how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SharePoint architecture and its environment differs entirely from Nodejs. There are many things that needs to be taken care of while deploying Nodejs application.

I assume you've developed some endpoints which you are trying to consume through SharePoint. In that case, the best solution is to create node environment in your on-premise server.

The other way could be deploy the Nodejs application on Azure. And allow access to your local environment only. This will protect your endpoints to get exposed. There are some security concerns that you may have to handle.

Much simpler approach is to deploy on Heroku and try to access from your SharePoint

**https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest would be to deploy the REST API directly to IIS and consume it from there. If you want it to be more like a deliverable product, so you can still have the wsp file which can be deployed, you should create a WCF Service.

http://sharepointwiththili.blogspot.com/2016/03/create-custom-wcf-service-for.html

This can happily live in an already created solution and it can be deployed directly to SharePoint.

Comment: But REST API was built in node JS. Facing tough time deploying in IIS.